Why are good car speedometers so slow?
I was looking at a youtube of someone breaking on the autobahn, and decided to plot the speed (below).  What immediately strikes me is how slowly the speedometer updates, only twice per second.  That is glacial for any "normal" computer, and quite noticeable to a human.
I do not know what car this is, but it is a newish Mercedes and is still accelerating at 281 kph so this must be a pretty expensive car with a certain amount of effort put into the "look and feel".  It would seem odd for them to make something so obvious slow for no good reason, and to have it updating more frequently must be easy to do.
Why does the speedometer update so slowly in this car?

Note: Frame rate 60/fps Speed in km/h.

Ask the engineers who made it? I don't think you'll be able to get a knowledgeable answer, but that'd be my opinion.

My guess is to reduce visual clutter and avoid dragging focus away from driving. Humans are very good at looking at things that change or blink.

It's so that you can read it.
I worked in instrumentation for a number of years, and it is normal for an instrument to update a digital display twice a second, otherwise you'll only see a blur of numbers when the speed is changing rapidly.
You only glance at the speedometer from time to time, when you want to immediately see a clear speed. Nobody drives with their eyes glued to it, especially under hard acceration or braking. One drives according to the road, not to instrument displays.
Being in an expensive car does not change that. It is not a failure of its engineering but a design decision.

I guess my comment to the OP was wrong. This makes a lot of sense ... something I was actually wondering. +1

Having driven a car (not a Mercedes) with a digital speedo that did update rather more frequently than twice a second I can confirm that it was a decidedly unpleasant experience.

It can't be because car electronics are not capable of fast updates, so it must be a conscious decision.
Consider --
Suppose you have 6 cylinder car cruising along at just 2000 rpm. There's one or another cylinder firing 100 times per second. That means, depending on the specific engine, that the car's electronics are deciding 100 times per second exactly when to fire the spark plug within the allowed advance / retard window, exactly how much fuel to inject if it's a direct injection engine, etc. It seems certain that if the engineers wanted to update the speedometer 100 times per second, it would surely be feasible.
Why do we have speedometers anyway? To monitor our speed in order to maintain a steady speed for fuel economy, or to avoid exceeding a given speed for legal and safety reasons. We adjust speed by altering foot pressure on the gas pedal.
How many times per second can you alter foot pressure? More than twice per second?
What happens when you drive a digital display for a rapidly changing value with updates at an unlimited frequency? All you see is a flickering 8 for the rightmost digits, meaning that all segments are lighting many times per second and the persistence of vision blurs them all into an 8. It's useless.
Then there's the problem of displaying a digital value in an analog world. We've all seen digital displays of steady analog values that switch back and forth between sequential digits, like a 6 changes to a 7, then goes back to 6 because the value is actually 6.5. If you allow this more than about 15 times per second, you won't see a 6 or a 7, you'll see an 8.
And let's face it, wouldn't it be annoying to glance at a speedometer for a moment and not see an exact speed because it changed during the fraction of a second that your glance lasted?
Mercedes engineers had to decide on a refresh rate for digital speedometers somewhere between "so fast that it's a blur" and "every now and then". Being Mercedes engineers, I'd bet that they involved their experts in Human Factors. Those who designed the car in the video settled on twice per second. I'd say they made a reasonable choice for every purpose except graphing a vehicle speed from a YouTube video!
